# How to return tuple with max and its index

Tags: python

Function named minmax_index has two parameters: one of type list and another type bool. If the Boolean parameter refers to True, the function returns a tuple containing the minimum and its index; and if it refers to False, it returns a tuple containing the maximum and its index.

eg: minmax_index([1,2,3,4],False)

(4,3)

Please modify it to make it work if possible,

Thanks,

Comment: Style hint: Don't use `if x == True:`, just write `if x:`. And use `else:` for the opposite condition.

Comment: does feel like homework

Comment: What is the question/problem here?

Answer (score 0):

itertae through the list and keep record of minimum and maximum element and their index

```
def mimax(lst, b):
    if not lst: 
        return []
    min_val, min_index = lst[0], 0
    max_val, max_index = lst[0], 0


    for i, v in enumerate(lst):
        if min_val > v:
           min_val = v
           min_index = i
        if max_val < v:
           max_val = v
           max_index = i
    return  (min_val, min_index) if b else (max_val, max_index)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid looping by using the in-built functions:

```
def mimax(lst, b):
    
    if not b:
        return (max(lst), lst.index(max(lst)))
    else:
        return (min(lst), lst.index(min(lst)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified, which index to return if there are multiple values with the min or max, so I leave it up to chance.

```
def minmax_index(lst, b):
    fun=min if b else max
    return fun([(b,a) for a,b in enumerate(lst)])
```